# How to decrypt data in arxml

Tags: c++, autosar, automotive

I'm writing an arxml handling app to decode/encode car data using arxml files. This works pretty well so far but now I have SECURED-I-PDUs. I found no spec or docu that describes how to handle this in a way that is understandable. Can someone explain how to apply decryption on those PDus? I parsed these SECURE-COMMUNICATION-PROPS-SET and ND-TO-END-PROTECTIONS node, but have no glue how to get things together. I'm using c++.

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood: that's not encryption, only authenticity and integrity. So all you have to do is understand how to strip the MAC and the sequence number to get back to the classic ISignalIPdu.

Comment: That's all? Just to 'unpack' the I-Signal-IPDU from the SecureIPDU?...Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's all.